# Remove text from a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have an AD extract with over 54000 names that are generally in this format (Sample Data):

```
Barnes, Bob B [WST]  
Santiago, Francis AB [AT]  
Chandler, Ronald  
Jefferson,  Katherine T [NT]  
Forrest,  Stan S  [WST]  
El Guerrero,  Annette BMD [AT]  
Lopez,  Todd TA  [CNT]  
Jackson, Lincoln F [NT]  
Nunez, Mattie Joey LC [WST]  
Moran,  David DA [AT]  
Gowan, Darryl V  
Hansen,  Rick AF  [NT]  
Lowe,  Denise DR  [WST]  
Butler,  Doug D  [AT]  
Kim, Erika
```

Unfortunately, this format is not consistent throughout the data. At times, there will not be a MI or there may be up to 3 MI's. Also, the [RGN] isn't always present. And to make it worse, there are a fair amount of names that have spaces in them as well (ex. Da Vinci).

I need to clean up these names so they read:
LastName, FirstName

I have tried using LEFT, RIGHT and Text-to-Columns functions with minimal success. So far, the best result is the Text-to-Columns methode delimited by a space and then joining them using (a1&" "&b1). This only works for maybe half the names and currently, I plan to continue joining cells (a1&b1&c1 etc) and then manually checking the names to make sure they are correct. I am praying and hoping that someone can save me and my eyes from doing this and has an idea for me to try.

Comment: What is "MI" is that always like this? Please post some sample data, without knowing your data it's really difficult to help effectively.

Comment: @MátéJuhász - MI = Middle Initial
Current Data: Smith, Bob BS [CA]
Prefered Format: Smith, Bob
Also, as stated in my OP, the data is not consistent with the middle initials or even the region (text within brackets).

Comment: Are you actually looking for help or just want confirmation that your workaround is the best one?  If you need help then please post 10-15 sample names with desired output to help us understand your data.

Comment: "with desired output".  please edit your question instead of posting data in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [RegEx Find/Replace add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) to have regular expression enabled worksheet function.

With that you can easily remove MI & RGN:

`=RegExReplace(A1," [A-Z ]*(\[.*)*","",-1)`

1. Find pattern `" [A-Z ]*(\[.*)*"`

   - matches space after the name
   - `[A-Z ]*` optionally matches initials
   - `(\[.*)*` optionally matches region
2. replaces it to nothing `""`
3. only replaces the last occurrence `-1`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression, or something like it, to split that string into three parts.  LastName, FirstName, extra.

You can probably use the same functionality to split the extra into MI and RGN, assuming you have a short list of RGN (regions?).

Using the comma as a delimiter to pull the lastname off the front is easy.  Finding the firstnames with spaces might be harder.  However, assuming that the ones with 3 MIs have single initials, you could look for the first single character as the first middle initial.  Anything before that is the first name.

Whatever you do, do it in stages.  Pull the lastnames off, since that's easy.  The remainder is FirstName MI [RGN].  If the brackets exist where there's a region, it makes that easy as well.  Strip those off.

That leaves FirstName MI.  I'd work right to left.  If the last character is a space, drop it.  If it's a character, and the character left of it is a space, then it's an initial.  Pull it out and add it to the front of the destination field for MI.  Repeat until there's a multicharacter string.  This is the end of the FirstName.  Congrats, you're done splitting it all out.

Another question:  Can you go back to AD and re-export and get the individual fields and not the display name?  (powershell, `Get-ADUser ...`)  It'd be MUCH easier to reassemble the display name than it is to do what I just listed.

Comment: I'll try this out as the other way is just taking way too long. I guess there really isn't a nice single-step solution to this, ha. Btw, I have both First and Last names with spaces (ex. De La Piccard, Jean Luc). Ugh!
The RGN are regions as you guessed and they are always in brackets when they do exist, so quite easy to strip those off.
Unfortunately, I can't go back and have them split the names out as I have to go to another department who has that access and the turnaround time is longer that I have time for. Will keep you posted...thanks!

Comment: FYI, you may underestimate your access to Active Directory.  Assuming Windows 8 or later, if you can run powershell at all, try this at the commandline.  `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\aduserdump.csv`.  Everyone has read access to AD.  Where this won't work is if you have multiple domains.  If so, it gets complicated.

Comment: I was able to make things work a bit faster with what you suggested, but still not fully cleaned up. I appreciate the help though!

Process I used:
1. Pulled all the last names using Text-to-Columns with a comma as the delimiter.
2. Removed all text with brackets to get rid of the regions.
3. TRIM to remove space after name.
4. Removed all text from last space to end using formula: =LEFT(D16,FIND("^^",SUBSTITUTE(D16," ","^^",LEN(D16)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D16," ",""))))-1)
5. Joined cells back together using =A16&", "&D16
Not perfect or fast, but does the trick. Thanks!